# What are the main things that should be considered while deallocating the memory in C?

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks

I tried to find some tutorial which explicitly explains,what are the things that need to keep in mind while deallocating the memory. But I could not find the such things.Can anybody let me know what are the principal things that a programmer should keep in mind while deallocting the memory in C. I am currently dealing with linked lists.There are some cases where a new linked list is created using 2 or more existing linked list.For example:

```
 list l1;
 list l2 
 list l3 = list_append(l1,l2)
 list l4 = list_append(l3,l1)
 list l5 = list_append(l3,l4)
```

What is the sequence of deallocation that i have to follow to deallocate the memory?

here list_append is the function that returns the copy of the list.

Comment: Impossible to say without knowing what `list_append` does. Does it copy the input lists, or just link them together?

Comment: @Steve the list append copies the input lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using the `malloc`/`free` family of function there are two rules to be obeyed.

1. You can only `free` valid memory returned by a `malloc` family allocator, and freeing it renders it invalid (so double freeing is an error as is freeing memory not obtained from malloc).
2. It is an error to access memory after it has been freed.

And here is the important part: **the allocator provides *no* facilities to help you obey these rules**.

You have to manage it yourself. This means that you have to arrange the logic of your program to insure that these rules are always followed. This is c and huge amounts of tedious and complex responsibility are dumped on your shoulders.

Let me suggest two patterns that are fairly safe:

Allocate and free in the same context

```
//...
{
  SomeData *p = malloc(sizeof SomeData);
  if (!p) { /* handle failure to allocate */ }
  // Initialize p

  // use p various ways

  // free any blocks allocated and assigned to members of p
  free p;
}
//...
```

Here you know that the data p points to is allocated once and freed once and only used in between. If the initialization and freeing of SomeData's contents are non-trivial you should wrap them up in a couple of function so that this reduces to

```
//...
{
  SomeData *p = NewSomeData(i,f,"name"/*,...*/); // this handles initialization
  if (!p) { /* handle failure to allocate */ }

  // use p various ways


  ReleaseSomeData(p) // this handles freeing any blocks 
                     // allocated and assigned to members of p
}
//...
```

Call this one "Scope Ownership". You'll note that it is not much different from local automatic variables and provides you with only a few options not available with automatic
variables.

Call the second option "Structure Ownership": Here responsibility for deleting the allocated block is handed to a larger structure:

```
List L = NewList();
//...

while (something) {
  // ...
  Node n= NewNode(nodename);
  if (!n) { /* handle failure to allocate */ }
  ListAdd(L,n);               //  <=== Here the list takes ownership of the 
                              // node and you should only access the node 
                              // through the list.
  n = NULL; // This is not a memory leak because L knows where the new block is, and
            // deleting the knowledge outside of L prevents you from breaking the
            // "access only through the structure" constraint.
  //...
}

// Later
RemoveListNode(L,key); // <== This routine manages the deletion of one node 
                       // found using key. This is why keeping a separate copy
                       // of n to access the node would have been bad (because
                       // your separate copy won't get notified that the block
                       // no longer valid).

// much later
ReleaseList(L); // <== Takes care of deleting all remaining nodes
```

Given as you have a list with nodes to be added and removed, you might consider the Structure Ownership pattern, so remember: once you *give* the node to the structure you *only* access it through the structure.

Answer (score 2):

The question in general makes little sense, the only reasonable answer seems rather obvious:

1. That the memory was dynamically allocated in the first instance
2. That following deallocation you do not attempt to use the memory again
3. That you maintain at least one pointer to the allocation until you need to deallocate it (i.e. don't let your only reference to the block go out of scope or be destroyed).

This second requirement can be assisted by setting the pointer to NULL or zero after deallocation, but the pointer may be held elsewhere to it is not fool-proof.

The third requirement is particularly an issue in complex data structures where the allocated memory may contain structures that themselves contain pointers to allocated memory.  You will of course need to deallocate these prior to deallocating the higher level structure.

Answer (score 2):

> Can anybody let me know what are the
>   principal things that a programmer
>   should keep in mind while deallocting
>   the memory in C.

The basic principles are pretty straightforward: any memory allocated using the *alloc family of functions, including `malloc`, `calloc` or `realloc`, must be deallocated by a corresponding call to `free()`.

When passing a pointer (memory address) to `free()`, keep in mind that the *only* valid memory addresses you can pass to `free()` are memory addresses which were previously returned by one of the *alloc functions.  Once a memory address has been passed to `free()`, that memory address is no longer valid and cannot be used for any other purpose.

Answer (score 1):

The first principle is:

> Whatever you allocate (with calloc /
>   malloc) you need to free eventually.

In you case if lists are **deep copied** on every append, I don't see what is the problem. You need to free every list separately.

Comment: does it mean that ,once you allocate the memory, immediately free the memory for the list eventhough the particular list is going to reuse again in the following lines?I tried to free the memory at the end of my program, it is showing me some error.

Comment: You delete something when you don't need it any more. In you case you can delete it in any order anywhere if those are really deep copies. Probably your problem is how you are deleting those lists. Post your code and we will try to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use valgrind(1) to show you, in your particular case, what objects still exist at termination and then modify your code to ensure that unnecessary ones are freed.

Answer (score 0):

Well the best answer is a question.. why the heck are you writing code in C instead of using a higher level language with better memory management?